# Seleccionar solo algunos valores de la tabla con select

Tags: mysql

tengo una tabla llamada unidads en la cual tengo el id y el nombre de la unidad:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora lo que necesito es seleccionar solo algunos items del total de la tabla, por ejemplo: Operaciones, mantencion, etc. es posible hacerlo en la consulta select? alguna vez vi algo similar pero olvide el comando y no recuerdo como hacerlo.

Saludos a todos

Comment: Osea en el ejemplo veo 11 registros y necesitas traer por ejemplo solo 3? Ejemplo: los primeros.. es correcto?

Comment: claro, necesito mostrar solo algunos de los 11, no necesariamente los 3 primeros

Comment: Puedes usar un *IN* por ejemplo: _SELECT * FROM unidads WHERE id IN (1,2,3)_  y traerá los primeros 3y puedes modificar para que sea los ids que necesitas por ejemplo el _(3,6,7)_ y traerá Tics,Dialisis,Direccion

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer una selección especifica necesitas utilizar el comando WHERE, un ejemplo es el siguiente:

```sql
SELECT * FROM nombre_de_tabla WHERE (aqui va tu condicion para seleccionar los datos)
```

Comment: Hola, si con el where podria traer por ejemplo where = 'Operaciones', pero queria ver si hay una opcion de seleccionar sin hacer 3, 4 wheres

Comment: Podrias usar el operador logico `OR`. Por ejemplo:
`SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE (unidad = 'Operaciones' OR unidad = 'Mantencion' OR unidad = 'algo');`
Tal vez no es la forma mas sofisticada de hacerlo, pero para el problema puede funcionar.

Comment: `WHERE` no es un comando, es una cláusula de sentencia.